# GeoDjango GDAL_ERROR when uplading .shp

Tags: django, geodjango

Try to parse a .shp in django shell:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
ds = DataSource('/Users/.../Downloads/Iceland.shp')
```

get:

```
GDAL_ERROR 4: Unable to open /Users/.../Downloads/Iceland.shx or /Users/.../Downloads/Iceland.SHX.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 78, in __init__
    raise GDALException('Could not open the datasource at "%s"' % ds_input)
GDALException: Could not open the datasource at "/Users/.../Downloads/Iceland.shp"
```

File exists, chmod is 755, .shx file is correct (tested in online services).
Then I try to test .kml file and it works

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: I would try a few more things: 1. Check the mandatory .shx, .shp and .dbf files are in the same directory. 2. Check no other programs have the shapefile open (and locked). 3.  Open the shapefile in QGIS/ArcGIS and validate geometry. 4. Try another shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing "Iceland.shx" file. It should be in the same archive as Iceland.shp. Just put it in the same directory. I've tried this files: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/iceland-shapefile and catch same error.

If it will not help, there some other options how to debug:

1. Check the mandatory .shx, .shp and .dbf files are in the same directory.
2. Check no other programs have the shapefile open (and locked).
3. Open the shapefile in QGIS/ArcGIS and validate geometry.
4. Try another shapefile

Answer (score 0):

I need to add that I have the same error when I tried to run the command:

```
python manage.py ogrinspect /map/data/points.shp BuildingFootprints --srid=4326 --mapping --multi
```

And the error was generated because of a backslash before the map, so it passed when I run:

```
python manage.py ogrinspect map/data/points.shp BuildingFootprints --srid=4326 --mapping --multi
```

When I was looking for my solution I found this question, which is answered. Anyway, I wanted to post this answer for those people who came here like I do a few min ago. Maybe someone help.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py ogrinspect map/data/points.shp BuildingFootprints --srid=4326 --mapping --multi
```

Ensure your data is located in the folder... map/data/points.shp BuildingFootprints