How to store a `.shp` file to gisModel.GeometryField in model?
I have an example shp file and a model as follow
class PolygonShape(models.Model):
    ...
    geometry = gisModel.GeometryField(null=False, srid=25832)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

I want to upload the shp file and store it at GeometryField of the model. However, i dont know how to do it

This is my so far try :

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        shapefile = request.FILES.get('shapefile')
        if not shapefile:
            return GeneralErrorResponse(data={"error": "No shapefile provided"}).to_json_response()

        save_directory = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'shapefiles')
        if not os.path.exists(save_directory):
            os.makedirs(save_directory)

        # Create the full file path
        file_path = os.path.join(save_directory, shapefile.name)

        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in shapefile.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

        ds = DataSource('/uploads/shapefiles')

But got error of
raise GDALException('Could not open the datasource at "%s"' % ds_input)
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Could not open the datasource at "./uploads/shapefiles/multipoint.shp"


Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508876/geodjango-gdal-error-when-uplading-shp ? Do you have shx and other related files in the directory ? Your error seems to be related to reading the shapefile rather than storing it into the database.
